# How to rewrite a long URL with numerical value to short url with same value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please Help with non-stardart Long URL

```
http://example.com/media/player/player.swf?f=http://example.com/media/player/config.php?vkey=12345
```

Want rewrite to short URL

```
http://example.com/embed/12345
```

Comment: Can you post your full htaccess configuration, and everything else that could be relevant

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean it the other way around, if someone request `http://example.com/embed/12345` you want this internal rewritten to `http://example.com/media/player/player.swf?f=http://example.com/media/player/config.php?vkey=12345`

If so this works as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?embed/([^/]+)$ /media/player/player.swf?f=http://example.com/media/player/config.php?vkey=$1 [L]
```

If you really want it the other way around than you have to do it like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f=http://example\.com/media/player/config\.php\?vkey=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?media/player/player\.swf$ /embed/%1 [L]
```

If you want a redirect than change `[L]` to `[R=301,L]`

Comment: Not the other way round. I just need the second option (make short URL like example.com/embed/12345. Sorry, but your code does`t work.

Comment: Do you need a redirect or a rewrite? see: stackoverflow.com/a/46595140/5427950

Comment: I think i need 301 redirect from http://www.pornogovno.net/media/player/player.swf?f=http://www.pornogovno.net/media/player/config_embed.php?vkey=1260 because in new version of script shold be shortly URL

Comment: I do not understand why this code does not work. Even 301 redirect from the old domain ru to net does not work for the links of such a plan. all other links are redirected without problems